# there are no "Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost" and "Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost" in nuget

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, ninject

I want to create an ASP.NET WebAPI project with Ninject, I usually referenced Ninject OWIN based DLLs, but I cannot find "Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost" and "Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost" in nuget. Are they renamed or Ninject doesn't support OWIN based WebAPI any more?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with the auto generated "NinjectWebCommon.cs" file, we don't need to call
  `app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() =>`
`{`
`var kernel = new StandardKernel();`
`kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`
`return kernel;`
`}).UseNinjectWebApi(configuration);` 
  which are included in the DLLs mentioned in the question title in the `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method.